# Review Board Authentication

Tags: php, json, authentication, review-board

I have a review board running on different server . I am using review board as a normal user of it and can comment on the reviews create it but i am not the admin f it. In order to view the review request or comment on it, i need to authenticate with it with my username and password. This is the access given to me. Review Board is an open source tool which is used by many organisations.

Here are the WEB API of it:- (authenticating link) http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.5/webapi/2.0/authenticating/#logging-in

Now i am using wamp as server on my local system . I am using php as server side language. I want to use the Review Board API for fetching the data with my credientals. I am using php curl and written this code for authenticating:-

```php
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://SERVERIP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Basic realm="Web API"')); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Basic md5encryptedusernamepassword')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
$output = curl_exec($ch);  
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);  
var_dump($info);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($output);

?>
```

This code is not authenticating. Please have a look. Any kind of guideline will be helpful. I have spent much time understanding it. Please help.

Comment: Hi Prateek - do you realise that everyone reading this now knows your login IP, username and password?

Comment: It's timing out for me. Are you seeing any errors in the logs on the server or your php client?

Comment: hey, thanks adam i edited it and that server ip is accessible for some ips only so not a major issue but still much thanks for it.. any help to do the same ?

Comment: Editing a question here usually doesn't hide secret details, such as passwords - old versions are still visible. I'll report to mod. Meanwhile @pamincognito you should change your password straight away!

Comment: oh thanks @halfer i am new on stackoverflow!! thanks

Comment: ^ No probs. See my edit above, re changing your password.

Comment: I will not be very helpful but my suggestion could save you some time and work if you know Python. You could re-use all the authentication and RB API code used by rbtools (post-review) tool. I have done this myself to create a simple script to extract data from RB server. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You should set headers with key:"Authorization",value:" Basic #{Base64.encode64("username:password")}"。
Then you can access the api which is need authentication.